# Youtube video can't play over 2G or 3G network

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I have created an app in which I am playing youtube video using YouTube API. Over wifi, it works fine but when I play using 2g or 3g network it displays error message "An Error occurred, touch to retry."

Here my YouTube API code.

```
package com.example.userone.asianconnections.Activity;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.userone.asianconnections.Config;
import com.example.userone.asianconnections.R;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;

/**
 * Created by userone on 3/14/16.
 */
public class YouTubeVideoActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {


    private static final int RECOVERY_REQUEST = 1;
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;
    String video_url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.youtube_video);

        youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.youtubevideoId);
        youTubeView.initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        video_url = intent.getStringExtra("videoLink");

        Log.e("link is ", video_url+"");

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

        if(!b){
            youTubePlayer.cueVideo(video_url);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        if(!youTubeInitializationResult.isUserRecoverableError()){

            youTubeInitializationResult.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_REQUEST).show();
        }else{
            String error = String.format(getString(R.string.player_error), youTubeInitializationResult.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == RECOVERY_REQUEST){

            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
        }

    }
    protected YouTubePlayerView getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return youTubeView;
    }

    private void showMessage(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }




    private final class MyPlaybackEventListener implements YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener {

        @Override
        public void onPlaying() {
            // Called when playback starts, either due to user action or call to play().
            showMessage("Playing");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPaused() {
            // Called when playback is paused, either due to user action or call to pause().
            showMessage("Paused");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopped() {
            // Called when playback stops for a reason other than being paused.
            showMessage("Stopped");
        }

        @Override
        public void onBuffering(boolean b) {
            // Called when buffering starts or ends.
        }

        @Override
        public void onSeekTo(int i) {
            // Called when a jump in playback position occurs, either
            // due to user scrubbing or call to seekRelativeMillis() or seekToMillis()
        }
    }

    private final class MyPlayerStateChangeListener implements YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void onLoading() {
            // Called when the player is loading a video
            // At this point, it's not ready to accept commands affecting playback such as play() or pause()
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaded(String s) {
            // Called when a video is done loading.
            // Playback methods such as play(), pause() or seekToMillis(int) may be called after this callback.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdStarted() {
            // Called when playback of an advertisement starts.
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoStarted() {
            // Called when playback of the video starts.
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoEnded() {
            // Called when the video reaches its end.
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason errorReason) {
            // Called when an error occurs.
        }
    }
 }
```

and here is my Layout XML file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/youtubevideoId">

    </com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please, provide a more specific question with some of your code. This is too broad.